# How do I locate the data of host and kernel in two different locations

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, opencl

I have wrote the kernel code that will be run on FPGA device. Currently, I am writing the host code which will be run on CPU. In the last meeting with my professor, he told me that the data (arrays in my case) in the host should not be located in the same memory space of that for the device. Thus, he asked me to use pointers for the data in the host part.

Actually, 1- I am not sure if I understand why the data should be in two different location.

2- how to use pointers to use different memory location.

3-bellow are the arrays in the host. Any idea how to convert these arrays into pointers?

```
int array_X_set[5430][20];
int array_Y_set[5430];

for (int i = 0; i < 5430; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        array_X_set[i][j] = array_X_dataset[i][j];
    array_Y_set[i] = array_Y_dataset[i];
}

int X_train[4344][20] = {};
int Y_train[4344] = {};
int X_test[1086][20] = {};
int Y_test[1086] = {};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have allocated your arrays on the stack. This limits the maximum error size. It is better to use heap allocation with (1-dimensional) pointers:

```c
int* array_X_set = new int[5430*20]; // linearize 2D array
int* array_Y_set = new int[5430];

for (int i = 0; i < 5430; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        array_X_set[i+j*5430] = array_X_dataset[i+j*5430];
    array_Y_set[i] = array_Y_dataset[i];
}

int* X_train = new int[4344*20];
int* Y_train = new int[4344];
int* X_test = new int[1086*20];
int* Y_test = new int[1086];
```

At the end of your code, don't forget to free the allocated memory again. For every `new[]` there must be one corresponding `delete[]`:

```c
delete[] array_X_set;
delete[] array_Y_set;

delete[] X_train;
delete[] Y_train;
delete[] X_test;
delete[] Y_test;
```

All these arays are on the host (CPU) side in main system memory. On your device (FPGA), you need to allocate the same amount of (device) memory as OpenCL `Buffer` objects. Then you can copy the data over with `enqueueWriteBuffer()` and `enqueueReadBuffer()`.

Comment: Thank you for reply. So in this way the data in the host and in the kernel are allocated into two different memory locations ?? What about using `malloc` ??

Comment: Yes, host and device memory are in physically separate locations. `malloc` does host allocation just like the `new[]` operator.

Comment: What about passing these pointers in a function like this `split( array_X_set, array_Y_set, X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test);` Do I need to add `*` before each one ?

Comment: If you have a function declared as `split(int* X, int* y, ...) { ... }`, when you call the function, you hand over the pointers without `*`, like this: `split(array_X_set, array_Y_set, ...);`

Comment: I want to create function called `split` and pass the pointers that we just created using `new` into the function.  So, is this is the correct way to do that `void split( int * array_X_set[5430*20], int * array_Y_set[5430],
    int * X_train[4344*20], int * Y_train[4344],
    int * X_test[1086*20], int * Y_test[1086]) {......}`  ???

Comment: please check my new question for today. I really need your help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69062671/how-to-use-array-of-pointer-in-functions?noredirect=1#comment122060088_69062671]